# ViewController as Subview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I have one `UIViewController` (DownloadManager) which downloads a webpage with `UIWebView` and display the downloaded content (say a pdf file). I want to use it as reusable component.

I am having another `UIViewController` pointing to a screen which contains 4 buttons each button should download and display one pdf file from webpage. I want to display the downloaded pdf as  a embedded subview to the current screen. Basically don't want navigation.

Here I tried to use DownloadManager as subview and display pdf as subview. Its working fine.

1. I read as Per screen one View Controller. But still can I use this approach ?
2. I have to send a email feedback from this screen. As soon as I present the MFMailComposeViewController the previous download manager subview disappears Technically what is happening here?

Please find the code snippet below:

```
//************************************************
@implement MyViewController

- (void) initWebView
{
    downloadMgr = [[DownLoadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DownLoadViewController" bundle:nil];

    downloadMgr.view.frame = CGRectMake(140, 20, 300, 200);
    downloadMgr.WebView.frame = CGRectMake(140, 20, 300, 200);

    downloadMgr.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    downloadMgr.WebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:downloadMgr.view];
    [self.view addSubview:downloadMgr.WebView];
}

----
----

- (IBAction)onHomeClick:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    switch (sender.tag) 
    {
        case 101: 
            {
                [self stopWebViewResources];
                if (!downloadMgr) {
                    [self initWebView];
                }
                downloadMgr.NavigationURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://xxx.yyyyyy.com/sites/pex/iPadFiles/abc.pdf"];        
                downloadMgr.title = @"ABC";
                [downloadMgr LoadURL];
            }
            break;

case 120:
        {
            //Send feedback via email
            if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) 
            {
                MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
                mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

                ----
                ----

                mail.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
                [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
//*****************************************************************


@interface DownLoadViewController : UIViewController <MyWebViewDelegate>{
    NSURL*                            NavigationURL;
    IBOutlet myWebView*              WebView;

    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView* ProgressView;
        NSString*                         DownloadedFileName; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is much more robust to separate the download functionality and the display into two different classes.

Ideally, you should have a class like "**Downloader**" or "**Download Manager**" which is a subclass of **`NSObject`**. This class should do the download and notify its **delegate** when it is done. Then you can have as many `UIViewController`s as you like that take advantage of your Downloader class.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am new to iOS programming. I am almost on the final stage of app delivery. So how about the 2nd case. why download manager is missing from MyViewController after presenting mail composer ?

Comment: I guess it is because theoretically you should only have one view controller and it gets confused. The surprise is that it worked in the first place.

Comment: View controller should control the logic to display the view. A dedicated Download Manager (ideally a singleton?) is by definition an object in the (data) Model layer.

Comment: Download Manager is a class which has members: a web view, ActivityIndicator View, etc as member. Not understanding how to make it derive from NSObject. It has a nib file as well. Adding Download manager class interface in the original question.

Comment: Exactly: you are misunderstanding the concept of the view controller. It should manage the relationship between data and the view. The download manager, on the other hand, should have the job to get the data, not manage the view. Read up on [encapsulation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Articles/ooObjectModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005149-CH5-SW10).